# In cakePHP's find(), how do I include a constant?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm looking to build a SQL query something like:

```
"SELECT email.member_id, 1 FROM email ... "
```

I'm using

```
$this->Email->find('list', array(
  'fields' => array('Email.member_id', '1'), ...
```

CakePHP is generating:

```
SELECT `Email`.`member_id`, `Email`.`1` FROM `emails` AS `Email` ...
```

How do I specify that the 1 is a constant and not a database field?

**Why I want to do this**

I basically want to return an associative array with keys of member_id and values of 1.  Would it be better to just get a straight array of member_ids and then transform that into my wanted data structure?  I thought this would be faster.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a perl programmer who's learning PHP, so a lot of the perl-isms I'm trying have other ways of working in PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cake does not easily allow that. In your specific case I would be wondering why you want to have a constant field anyways. But in general do to stuff like that you are supposed to use Virtual Fields:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1608/Virtual-fields

Basically you would modify model Email by adding this:

```
var $virtualFields = array(
   'one' => '1'
);
```

Now you can do your query like this:

```
$this->Email->find('list', array(
  'fields' => array('Email.member_id', 'Email.one'), ...
```

---

For the usecase you added you should just get a straight array of ids and fill it afterwards. Not only will be that faster, but also less hacky => easier to understand. You can do that easily with [´array_fill_keys()´](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-fill-keys.php).

Comment: @Chronial Thanks. This is perfectly working for Integer value but i need to do it for a string value. Can you suggest something?