# additionals properties of a model in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, ingres

I'm starting to use cakePhp and I would like to know:

When I do a query(like with $this->Product->find(...)), I receive an array, right?

Then:
-If I've some non-db fields with default values that I've to display for each product, how do I do?

I saw virtual fields, but I cannot manage to put a static var into it

Comment: Where are you getting these non-db fields from? I think we need a bit more context

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013958/in-cakephps-find-how-do-i-include-a-constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the solution Anh Pham provided another thing you could do, if it's just setting the values to display them, is add them to the array in  your controller after you have the results:

```
$result['Model']['desired_field_name'] = $static_field;
```

Comment: In fact I just realized now that we don't receive an object in the view, only an array, so yes I can add information like this. Thank you